# Cannot convert return expression of generic protocol's function type implementation

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'd like to use swift generics in a way described below:

```
class ResponseContainer {

}

protocol DisplayManageable {

    func getModel<ModelType: ResponseContainer>() -> ModelType?
}

class DisplayBaseManager<ObtainedModelType: ResponseContainer>: NSObject, DisplayManageable {

    var modelObtained: ObtainedModelType? = nil

    func getModel<ObtainedModelType>() -> ObtainedModelType? {

        return modelObtained
    }
}
```

But I have a problem with this code, more precisely there is a problem in this line:

```
return modelObtained
```

And I'm getting the error:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'ObtainedModelType?' to
>   return type 'ObtainedModelType?'

And now my simple question, why can't I do that? What's wrong with that?

Generics in protocol's function and in class definitions are the same. Everything looks fine in my opinion and logically is ok, so why cannot I do so?

Answer (score 2):

In

```
func getModel<ObtainedModelType>() -> ObtainedModelType? { ... }
```

`ObtainedModelType` introduces a *local* generic placeholder, and that
*hides* the `ObtainedModelType` from the class definition

```
class DisplayBaseManager<ObtainedModelType: ResponseContainer>
```

This causes the strange looking error message

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'ObtainedModelType?' to return type 'ObtainedModelType?'

because `return modelObtained` has the generic type `ObtainedModelType?` from the 
class definition, but the expected return type is `ObtainedModelType?`
from the method definition.

What you probably want is a protocol with an *associated type*

```
protocol DisplayManageable {
    associatedtype ModelType: ResponseContainer
    func getModel() -> ModelType?
}
```

and a class adopting this protocol with `ModelType == ObtainedModelType`:

```
class DisplayBaseManager<ObtainedModelType: ResponseContainer>: NSObject, DisplayManageable {

    var modelObtained: ObtainedModelType? = nil
    func getModel() -> ObtainedModelType? {
        return modelObtained
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Łukasz, I don't now why it doesn't compile but I found the way to compile it. Just change the return statement:

```
return modelObtained as? ObtainedModelType
```

But I'm still waiting for someone to explain the reason for error in the original code.

Comment: That would make it *compile*, but means that in a call to `manager.getModel()` the return is type is independent of the type of `manager`. You would have to call `let model = manager.getModel() as MyModelType?`, and that would return `nil` if the types don't match.